# Way to find an image inside another image in PHP/GD?

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I need a way to find the location of an image inside another image in PHP/gd. 
For example, locate this image:

[image]

inside this image:

[image: so_big.png]

I tried to make a function myself to do this, and I WAS successful, but it's very slow, it takes over 50 seconds at 100% CPU for me with the example pictures above, and I'm not sure how to optimize it (if possible) further. So is there some way to do this faster? Preferably, much faster? (For instance Auto Hotkey can do the same operation in <2 seconds on the same computer with this function https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm )

**Edit:** I figured I could simply create a copy of the small image by the big image's color indexes with imagecolorexact, this allows 2 things, detect when the small image has a pixel which doesn't exist in the big image, making a match impossible, AND comparing an `int(x)===int(x)` is much faster than comparing `array("red"=>x,"green"=>x,"blue"=>x)==array("red"=>x,"green"=>x,"blue"=>x)` - it looks like the speed nearly tripled this way, using 30 seconds before, using 9 seconds now. Still *nowhere near the speed* of AutoHotKey's though :/

```
$big = imagecreatefrompng ( 'so_big.png' );
$small = imagecreatefrompng ( 'so_small.png' );
bench ( __LINE__ );
var_dump ( FindImageInImageV2 ( $big, $small) );
bench ( __LINE__ );
die ( "DONED" );
function FindImageInImageV2($big, $small, int $max = PHP_INT_MAX,bool $center=true): array {
    assert ( is_resource ( $small ) );
    assert ( is_resource ( $big ) );
    $ret = array ();
    //think2 ( $big, 'FindImageInImage/big' );
    //think2 ( $small, 'FindImageInImage/small' );
    $smallx = imagesx ( $small );
    $smally = imagesy ( $small );
    $bigx = imagesx ( $big );
    $bigy = imagesy ( $big );
    assert ( $bigx >= $smallx );
    if ($bigx < $smallx) {
        return $ret; // match is impossible
    }
    assert ( $bigy >= $smally );
    if ($bigy < $smally) {
        return $ret; // match is impossible
    }
    $smallcolors = imagecolorstotal ( $small );
    $bigcolors = imagecolorstotal ( $big );
    // assert($smallcolors<$bigcolors);
    if ($smallcolors > $bigcolors) {
        return $ret; // too many colors, match is impossible.
    }
    $smallImageAsColors = array ();
    for($x = 0; $x < $smallx; ++ $x) {
        $smallImageAsColors [$x] = array ();
        for($y = 0; $y < $smally; ++ $y) {
            $tmp = imagecolorsforindex ( $small, imagecolorat ( $small, $x, $y ) );
            //unset ( $tmp ['alpha'] );
            $tmp=imagecolorexact ( $big, $tmp['red'], $tmp['green'],$tmp['blue']);
            if($tmp===-1){
                //small has a color that does not exist in big, match is impossible
                return $ret;
            }
            $smallImageAsColors [$x] [/*$y*/] = $tmp;
        }
    }
    unset ( $x, $y, $tmp );
    for($x = 0; $x < $bigx; ++ $x) {
        if ($bigx < ($x + $smallx)) {//<< todo: can be optimized away.
            break; // too close to the end, no result possible..
        }
        for($y = 0; $y < $bigy; ++ $y) {
            if ($bigy < ($y + $smally)) {//<< todo: can be optimized away.
                continue; // too close to the bottom, no result possible for this $y..
            }
            //$matchFound = true;
            for($i = 0; $i < $smallx; ++ $i) {
                for($ii = 0; $ii < $smally; ++ $ii) {
                    // yelp
                    if($smallImageAsColors [$i][$ii]!==imagecolorat($big,$x+$i,$y+$ii))
                    {
                        //$matchFound=false;
                        //goto outofmatching;//i can micro optimize the jumps more actually... but should i?
                        //goto uglyoptimize;
                        continue 3;
                    }
                }
            }
            //outofmatching:
            //if ($matchFound) {
                $ret [] = array (
                        'x' => ($center?$x+((int)floor($smallx/2)):$x),
                        'y' => ($center?$y+((int)floor($smally/2)):$y)
                );
                if (count ( $ret ) >= $max) {
                    //goto done;
                    return $ret;
                }
            //}
            //uglyoptimize:
        }
    }
    //done:
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Try to dig in the direction of pHash: http://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_automatically_identify_similar_images_using_phash Also check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29087466/4621324

Comment: A few thoughts, but no golden bullet. `If` statements hold up the flow of pipelined processing, and the first `if` statement in your `for($x` and `for($y` loops can be removed if you change the limits in the preceding for statement to `for($x=0; $x<$bigx-$smallx...`.

Comment: As you calculate the colours present in both images at the start, you could maybe get a couple of the rarest colours in your small image & rather than attempting a match in your inner loop by going through the pixels in the small image from top-left to bottom-right sequentially you could check the locations of the 2-3 rarest colours upfront & maybe reject the subimage quite quickly that way before falling into your main loop. Or maybe check the four corners & the middle which could also reject faster especially if the top-left of the image is white & the large image has large areas of white.

Comment: Another thought would be to reduce the sizes of the images and try a cross-correlation to find possibles matches to investigate further.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you! ill definitely do the if() optimizations, but the other suggestions sounds difficult, i don't feel like looking into those now, but ill come back to it next time i try to optimize it ^^