# Login virtual keyboard bank

Tags: php, forms, authentication, ocr, virtual-keyboard

There is a way to login programatically to website like bank which use a virtual keybord for the password ?

I found that i have to use an OCR to read the keyboard image(s). Its is the only solution ?

And if it is, what OCR I can use for ?

What is the name of this kind of login method ?

I know that its used for security purpose and it should not be easy to performance what I want etc... But that's what i wanted and some commercial tools can do that.

Thanks

Comment: Found this thing on icici bank, they use the letter in input value, so B => value="b". Do you have some specific site using this?

Comment: Site bank for example: bnp

Comment: Theres some function apply(), that is triggered on click, find this function and have a look inside..

Comment: I would check very carefully with your bank’s ToS etc., what they have to say about this … Liability for everything that happens to your account might be placed solely on you if you use any such measures.

Comment: I understand that, it also exists tierce commercials software for bank account stats/management which may use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`There is a way to login programatically to website like bank which use a virtual keybord for the password ?` - yes. if you're lucky, they have an API for it. otherwise, you gotta do the whole `pretend to be a human logging in` thing, which is often much more difficult.

`I found that i have to use an OCR to read the keyboard image(s). Its is the only solution ?` - in my experience, no. in theory, only the server may know the meaning of the coordinates clicked, making OCR-like behaviors required, but in every case i have inspected, the server told the client (the browser or game) the meaning of every button, taking away the need for OCR (because it's slightly less secure, but much easier to implement, and it protects against the main problem: keyloggers.)

edit: you specifically mentioned the BNP bank, i checked their login system on https://mabanque.bnpparibas/en/login , and there only the server does indeed know the meaning/locations of the keypads, that's a first! interesting indeed, there you indeed need some OCR-like behavior to login grammatically. luckily, it's rather trivial to detect the locations of the keys, since there's only 10 different ones (0-9) and their appearances are all static. check this out:

```
<?php
// get the real image binary from curl or something ofc, at https://mabanque.bnpparibas/identification-wspl-pres/grille/i-88243722402549998260015114166903914017
$imageBinary = base64_decode ( 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZ8AAACgCAYAAADTuWFYAAAYQUlEQVR4nO3dfXBU5b0H8O8G8gKEjX/0guStiEJIUqS1wG4iY8cqEHQsajEWxrEkJEKuFMTAjV4qWiv2Oje895YKGCy3w0yWhHaGsYQNceZOJdlNp+1cIS/6j4y74daOdtyTkLJkd8/9Y/dsssnm/eGc55DvZ4Y/dk+c+c3XPfvb5znPeY4FEfP3PJEEYCWAbAB3gUYTAvB3AB9f23e+feABZjluzFIcZikOsxRnSJbTAWD+nidSAfzoVxuq1hUuWGpPm5H6DQOLNAVVVUNfdP/De6mz1fUa8N61feedALOcCGYpDrMUh1mKEy/LaQBw10M5D9U8v3fLqlx7UUpi0kyjCzUDi8ViSU2emXZ/xsL8npu93Z/do3789R8/VZjl+DFLcZilOMxSnHhZJkSOLSi45367odWZ2MM5y/IALIi8ZJaTwCzFYZbiMEtxtCynR17PTJ6emKqqqpE1mZY1ZZYVgPYLiFlOArMUh1mKwyzF0bJMGPUviYiIBGPzISIi3bH5EBGR7th8iIhId2w+RESkO221G7hyYzJis2OWk8EsxWGW4jBLccLZceRDRES6Y/MhIiLdsfkQEZHueM1HgMHRMcuJY5biMEtxmKU4WnQc+RARke7YfIiISHdsPkREpDte8xFgcHbMcuKYpTjMUhxmKY6WHUc+RESkOzYfIiLSHZsPERHpjtd8BOB8sDjMUhxmKQ6zFIfXfIiIyDBsPkREpDtOuwlgliG5T1FQW1eHZpcbAFBot2Ht6tXIysw0uLJ+ZsnSDJilOMxSHC276aP8nTQ8Xi+sVivSrFajSzGlq+3tKHlhC3yKEn2v2eXCiZpTOHX8XXwrL8/A6syl2eUa8Xh+Xh4/p2Pk8XpxwemM/iBKs1pRaLfh2fXrDa7MfAZnmZWZibWrV6HQbje4svikbT4erxfHa07B4/VGT/b3j78rbZCy27FrNwDg7Td/ho3FxQCAMw4H/n3v69ixazea/vCBkeWZyqYXtox4nJ/TsYn3gwgALjidqK2rx6nj77KJj9FwWdbW1WHXSzvwQmmpQZUNT9ppN4/Xi9q6OgDhX0M+RYHFYpGuTgBDtryVrcZmlxserxcV5WUofvpp+P1+AEDx00/D4/Hg2ImTuHDRiaLVqwyuFNJnqcnOysKGSBOPd0yKuiXPsvrQYfgUBVWVlagoLwMQnhp+p3o/zjgcqD1bh/LSEoOrjDBhlp97PHjxpZ2oPnQY+bl5KLTbDK4yQvbVbt/Kz8f5+jpc6+zA1vJyo8sxtfbODgBAgc2GYDAYfT8YDKLAFv5Aeq93GVKbWWVlZqK8ZFPcf5kZGUaXJ7229nY0u1x4vKgI5SWb4Pf74ff7kZKcjJ+/vhdpVitOnDpldJmmMFyWd8+di6rKlwEALW63wVUOJW3zmZ2aipyFC+H3+xEKhYwux+QsAOL/Wut/z6JjPXeGYDAY959sv4pl1NYR/kGUn5cX84MIAAKBAFYWFsKnKFAGTSPRUFqWhXZ7TJaqqsK2fHnM38hE2uYDyDe0JSIxlO4eAEB+bm7c4/mRBTBX2+X70pSNlmW8EbfMP9ylveYTj6qqUtY5uCIZawTi5zfwtQx1myVLQO7aAHNkqaqhEUfkFoscdZs5y/7jctSsVSHtajcS50fPrMfSJUsw7+65RpdCRASAzWdKSJ01CyuWfVfakSMR3T7n6+uQn5uLW7duGV1KDJNMu4VrU1U565T97ueR6vnc4wUAWK2zpahb9iwHkrk2QPYsRzun5TrnzZzlovvui95eIQPT7XBAt0dDYyMA4EHeFDlubR0dUBQFmRmZyMrk8mqSk6yLDth8pihFUeCoP4dmlwtVlZVInzdPsl9zcrvc0oLLLS3R11mZGXh5+3YUrZLgRl2ashRFQbPbDa83fN9egd027IpCo5lk2q2fjHXKPSTv1+J2Y3PFv8a8V1FehrJNP0ZfX59BVcUyQ5Ybi4vxudeDBwsKAQBX29rwQUMDdv5bFXw/VVD89NMGVxhmhiw9Xi9sy5eN+Dcy1G2GLBsandixe3fsvVFHwjeXH3znP2CVZKsiTrtNQd/MzkZVZSUAQFF8OFPrwLETJzF37lxpvjDN4M29r8FisUSnMxISErChuBjPlZbi4JGjzHIMtL3vHPX1WP3I92O+GD1dXbhw0WlUaaZVW1ePBwsK8PjaImRnZsGn+PDrEyfR4nbjwNGjeGPPHqNLjMHmM4VkpKejbNOPo6+3lJXhe6tW44239qHAZkMWt4UZk3irhpZ/9wFsLC7GGYcDLW53dNsiii83JwcrCwvwUXMLnnnuOTwTadhtHR242HjJ4OrMqaqyEi+UlsTsslFot2PdM8Vw1J+Tt/nIOIzUaLWpkHOpsBmG5EC4roFfnEmJidhQXIxfnzyJ9vYOZKanG1hdmFmyHCwQCKDAZsMZhwPtnZ2wr1hhdElSZxkMBnFk/35UHzyEMw4HDhw5Gj22sbgYaWlWHDtxUppzXuYstVpycxbh5s2bMceSk5Lw2Jo1+PXJk2h2uVFgk+dzKfX2OnR7qaoa/TB2Xb9ucDXml5qaCgCwWLhP3likJCfjzb2v4VpnB35bU4Pf1tTgWmcH3tz7WjRLGrvQMDtFzJ4dzjJhmlxf95x2m+KC2jJMfl9OmjpkExYaiaqq0R2Ylz3wHQDAjRs3osdIDFmzNMW0W5Ssd+hLPCQHAG9XF9o6OpCfmzt080HJ9naTPcsRMcsJCwQC8Q/Ics6bIcvRspIsS7nGYXRbOJuaUPnKq5xaE8Db1YWz534HbxeffzQZiqLg4qVLaGltNboUMgibzxSQkBD+38xrEZPnbGrCz95+m418kto7P0HlK6+is/MTo0shg5hj2i1SmqwbY0q/3foI+UVfy7KH1uDXEtQ0UIKl//cas5w47XeQxWKJX5dk57zMWY6alaRZcuQzxSlKt9ElENEUxOYzBRTawzc8xrt5r6XVHfM3NHFs5OPn647/mOxmtwsAeLPuGGRlZgIY/lHZWpay7fHG5jMFLI7cTe44dw41vzkNV2srXK2t+Nnbv4Cj/hxWFhZgcU6O0WWaAhu5GFpTaXA2DjmmKN1odrmRnZWFYDCod2mmk7t4MQDg4qWmIccGZinbvVPmuOYzgIx1ynz3MxBexnq4uho7du3CwV/+MubYkvx8HK6uHn6pq85kzzJn0aJoI09NTYV9xXIAgKv1T9FGnrNokRRfmjJnGQgEUFFehmMnTqL8xW1Y/9STsM6eDaW7GzWnTwMAtmzeLE3NMmeZPu/u6NZOla+8ivVPPQkAQ7KU5dEK3Fh0iklKTMT7x4/D1fonXGlrAxBuPAW2Fejt7ZXqZJJZMBiMNvKa06ejJzfQ38hlaDxm8NK2bfD5FJxxOOAatOS6orwMP3xynXRP35RRKBTCzu0/wZW2NjibmuBsih0ByZqlKZpPeWkJtlVsRW9vrzS/0M1GVVX09vbigW8vxfLvPgAg/EWq3VFOY8dGLobf78cbP92DDc8W46Pm/mcjPV60BnPnzJHq6ZuyS0lOxu8dtWhxt0Y/k4DcWZpi2u3mzZtDNsyTicxD8sH6+vqkeXZPPGbIUlVV3LhxA99Zen90W5hgMIienh6DK4tlhiz/+c9/4p5vfhML7703+l5fX59057vsWaqqip6enpjPJCB3lqYY+RDJKBAIcCQuQDAY5FSlIGb6THK1GxER6c4U026yk31IbibMUhxmKQ6zFIfP8yEiIsOw+RARke7YfIiISHe85iMC54PFYZbiMEtxmKU4vOZDRERGYfMhIiLdsfkQEZHueM1HAKmfcmgyzFIcZikOsxSHTzIlIiLDsPkQEZHu2HyIiEh3vOYjAPd9EodZisMsxWGW4nBvNyIiMgybDxER6Y7Nh4iIdMfmQ0REuos2n+nT+UTtiUpKTg4BCGmvmeXEMUtxmKU4zFIcLUstwZ7EGck9ScGk1L6+PoRCoZH+W4qYNm0aUlJS0PPVZ18D6Im8zSwngFmKwyzFYZbiDM5Saz6djR3uD9ct/d4PZsyYYWR9ptPj7/367J+b/gLg08hbzHKCmKU4zFIcZinOwCy15uN66ez+WlVVQ0szFy6elTwz1cgCzeIL5au/1f/1Q9eFtstnr+07/2XkbWY5AcxSHGYpDrMUZ3CWFu3A/D1PJAD4NoBsADMNq9BcvgTQfm3fee/AN5nlhDBLcZilOMxSnLhZEhER6WbgyCcJwEqEO/ldhlVkHiEAfwfw8bV959sHHmCW48YsxWGW4jBLcYZkOR0A5u95IhXAj361oWpd4YKl9rQZqd8wsEhTUFU19EX3P7yXOltdrwHvXdt33gkwy4lgluIwS3GYpTjxspwGAHc9lPNQzfN7t6zKtRelJCZx/nIMLBaLJTV5Ztr9GQvze272dn92j/rx13/8VGGW48csxWGW4jBLceJlqd1kuqDgnvvthlZnYg/nLMsDsCDykllOArMUh1mKwyzF0bLUllrPTJ6emMptwifGmjLLiv4VL8xyEpilOMxSHGYpjpYl93YjIiLdsfkQEZHu2HyIiEh3bD5ERKQ7Nh8iItJd9KEUXLkxGbHZMcvJYJbiMEtxmKU44ew48iEiIt2x+RARke7YfIiISHe85iPA4OiY5cQxS3GYpTjMUhwtOo58iIhId2w+RESkOzYfIiLSHa/5CDA4O2Y5ccxSHGYpDrMUR8uOIx8iItIdmw8REemOzYeIiHTHaz4CcD5YHGYpDrMUh1mKw2s+RERkGDYfIiLSndTTbj5FQW1dHZpdbgBAmtWKQrsNz65fb3BlsTgkF0fmLD1eLzxe76h/l5WZiazMTB0qGpnMWWp4jos1OM9Cuw1rV6+W4vOo0bKbPsrfGeZqeztKXtgCn6LEvH/B6URtXT1OHX8XaVarQdWZW7PLBUCeL0mzaGhsxH8ePDTq3+3e+RLKS0p0qMjceI6LFS/PZpcLJ2pO4dTxd/GtvDwDqxtK2uZTfegwfIqCqspKVJSXAQh39Xeq9+OMw4Haujq8UFpqcJXmc8HpxI5duwHwS3K8luTno6qyctjjV9va8EFDAywWi45VmdeOXbtHPMerDx3Gz/e+ZnCV5qGd17+tqcHKwgIAwLETJ/HO/v3YsWs3mv7wgZHlDSHltFtbezuaXS48XlSE8pJN8Pv9AICU5GT8/PW9+KChASdqTsnzxWmSITkAtESG42EW+WqVOMsCmw2Fdvuwx6sPhUdFa1evlqNuibNscDbC4/Wiorws7jl+pa0NtXV12LVjO6wyjH4kzhLoz7OqshK25cuieZaXbIKi+HDsxElcuOhE0epVBleKaJZSLjjwdHUBAPLz8hAMBmOOBQIBrCwshE9RoAwartPoLjidyM7KMroMUwqFQggGg8P++6DhIpbk5yMjPd3oUqXnvR4+xwtstrjn+GNFawAAV9s7dK/NjLQ88xYvRigUir4fDAZRYLPF/I0spGw+Xq355ObGPZ4fmbvkB3N8auvq4VMUPLZmjdGl3HG0xQgPFhRI96tYTuGpyeGyCoUiv44TOIU5NlpOQ/Psz1iuLKVsPiMFCQy4SYkfzHFpaXVHVxORWA2NjQDAbInGSMprPhpVVUesa7TjehlcgQw1DaYoCi5cdGJDcXHMsFy2Ws2QZTwt7nBjt69YEZOvkcyQJc9xseLlNfC1DHVrFUi72o3Eami8BIC/zG8HRVFwucWFx4rWSNN4aGrZsrkUTzy2FjNmzDC6lDGTdNqNRGtxu5GdlYWiVRKsdrnDaI39wRFWwhHdToFAAHPnzIF19myjSxkzSafdwrWo6nB1jXZcX7Lf/awoCi44ndhaVoZAIDBg1agcUxoDyZ5lPO0d4YUva1atkqpembO0WsNfkp97vLAtXz7kuMfjAQBkZmRIUbfMWWqGq+ly9KZyubLkyGcKuHgp/MtcijX+d6ALTieW5OcjddYso0sxDW2UqC3UGEj7sZSdlYXMjAy9S7ujKIoCR1090qxW6WY92HymgBZ3K7KzspCbk2N0KXecFrcbPkXB2jVrpPhVaRbp8+ahorwMzS4XXn/rreg9ex5vF0orKsI7H7z8MjOdpP1HjsKnKNhaXjbkfiqjSTrt1m+0umSoW+YhuaerKzrlFu/DJ1OtgNxZxtPS2goAKLCtkK5WmbNUVRUvb9+OK21tcNSfg6P+XMzxqspKPPr9h6X5wpQ5y+E4zp2Do74eS/LzUbZpE/r6+owuCYAJNhYlMZyRi+FrVj1qcCV3pgZnI9KsVuTm5HCl2zgdO3ECHzW3IM1qxcZni2G1psHj8eCMw4F39u/Hovvujd6dT+PT4nbjjbf2Ic1qxdEDB6RpPAOx+dzhLl66FJ1y45ejWJ6uLni83iH3TtHoFEXBgSNHkWa14n8anZg1cyYAwGKx4LGiIjxXWooDR3+Js2w+49bW0YGdVa8gzWrFf9e8h7lz/kXKkZqU025aLeowq7FGO643WYfk3q4uXG1vHzLlpkZXC8qR30CyZhnPRW1XA5tNyjplzrLFHZ6u3FBcjKTERNy6dSt6bNkD38GS/HxcaWuDz+eTYmNRmbMcSFEUvPHWPiiKgv86eBAL771Xuh9GXO02BWir3Djldnu4Wv8EALCvGLpUmEbWdf06gPjXyoLBINZG9h9s7+zUvTYze+83p9HW0RG9ZiZb4xmIzecO5rzUhOysLCxetMjoUu44iqKg2eXCysICzOIS6/GLbMsYHObLMRQKj9QtCfyKGitvVxdOvv8+luTnY/OPn0cgEDC6pBFJOe0WNdq0kCzTRhIOyfun3DYPXTEk2V5PMSTMMh5tlVuh3S7vr0szZMlzXJiz534HANhStjlmGlM6XO12Z3M2NQEAPmpuwf9+fCXmmNLdDSD8iIXLzS3Y+ZNtyBvm8RUUX/+U2wqDKyEKO3vuHLKzsvDoww9LP+oB2HzuWAmR6Yqr7e3D/o32DJqynh69yrpjXGxsjE5pSjvyoSmjvaMDPkXBhuJnTNF4AFmn3SKlDLsaa7TjOpNxu/XykhJs27o17rGPmlvwXGkpqiorUVFeht7eXnlu5hv8WoIsB2vv6Iye6LLkFo/UWfIcF6rr+v8BADLS06WrbTCpH6mgPam0raMDK5YtG3K82R3eKC/eI3gp7NatW8PO+/r9NwEAwUAA3ZEpOBq7xg8/BADkLl5scCXmpyjxP3++bkXnSsxNe/pzhon2wpNyKUl6+jwAwMVLTUOOKUo3ml3hxwOw8ZARXJHFBqsfecTgSsxLe66UdjvAQIrSHd05gjscjI3FEnksuYmmgKUc+WSmp2NjcTHOOByofPVVPPPUUwDCH8r3Tp8GAGzZvNnIEmmK0lYRPl5UZJq5dRktzsnBysICNDQ2IqSGhpzjHq8XVZUv8wfmOB04chSzh3mmz5pHH8H6SM4ykPKaTzAYxM7tP8GVtjY4LzXBOWgEtLG4GD98cp00ywnNcvdzPLLVKnuW2irCvNzF0tU2mMxZBgIBHK6uxo5du+Ke4xXlZSh9/nn4/X6DKowlc5YDtUWeLRXPgwV2KeqWfmPRlORk/N5Ri/bOTnzU3BJ9//GiNbh77lzcvHnTwOpoqtpaVoYdL74Iv98vzRejWSUlJuL948fR8ckn0XM8Lc2KlQUFmDtnDvMdh/LSEmyriL/ASCPbZ1ba5qOqKm7cuIEF8+dj0X33Rd/v6+tj45mkApsN1zo7pPswmgEzE0dVVfT29sac46qqIhAIMONxMuPnUsppt4ECgYD0c+tmGZJr+vr64PP5jC4jLrNlKTOzZMlzfGrhxqJERGQYNh8iItKd9NNuZsAhuTjMUhxmKQ6zFIfTbkREZBg2HyIi0h2bDxER6Y7XfETgfLA4zFIcZikOsxSH13yIiMgobD5ERKQ7Nh8iItIdr/kIIPtTDs2EWYrDLMVhluJoyXHkQ0REumPzISIi3bH5EBGR7njNRwDu+yQOsxSHWYrDLMXh3m5ERGQYNh8iItIdmw8REemOzYeIiHQXbT7Tp08f6e9oBEnJySEAIe01s5w4ZikOsxSHWYqjZakl2JM4I7knKZiU2tfXh1AoNNJ/SxHTpk1DSkoKer767GsAPZG3meUEMEtxmKU4zFKcwVlqzaezscP94bql3/vBjBkzjKzPdHr8vV+f/XPTXwB8GnmLWU4QsxSHWYrDLMUZmKXWfFwvnd1fq6pqaGnmwsWzkmemGlmgWXyhfPW3+r9+6LrQdvnstX3nv4y8zSwngFmKwyzFYZbiDM7Soh2Yv+eJBADfBpANYKZhFZrLlwDar+077x34JrOcEGYpDrMUh1mKEzdLIiIi3fw/DsxfURPiNkUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' );
$keyLocations = BNPPinDecode ( $imageBinary );
print_r ( $keyLocations );
function BNPPinDecode(string $imageBinary): array {
    $img = function (string $imageBinary) {
        $ret = imagecreatefromstring ( $imageBinary );
        if (! $ret) {
            throw new \RuntimeException ( 'image format not recognized! (invalid binary?)' );
        }
        return $ret;
    };
    static $dictionary = NULL;
    if ($dictionary === NULL) {
        $dictionary = array (
                0 => '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',
                1 => 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAbCAYAAABfhP4NAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuMjHxIGmVAAAAqklEQVQoU63NPw7CIBiHYW7iqJOb3sVJT+Git2jTol5FKe0RTEd7gbYL0L/Tz4D51G5aJXn5CE8CrO97vHfLMuRFAWYP290eq/UGk+nMFcUxmN3oYr5YuimTBKwoS1zTFHYFx9MLuq5zb9vp88MQqAG0bQuKwH3+PTRNA8rn3IGQo6Cua1A/QlVVoLwwdHCRcgwYY0A9IYrGgNYalBc84CzEX0EpBeoDELgDlVv5PQaPGnIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=',
                2 => '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',
                3 => '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',
                4 => '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',
                5 => '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',
                6 => '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',
                7 => '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',
                8 => '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',
                9 => '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' 
        );
        $dictionary = array_map ( $img, array_map ( 'base64_decode', $dictionary ) );
        register_shutdown_function ( function () use (&$dictionary) {
            array_map ( 'imagedestroy', $dictionary ); // free up memory... php probably would do this anyway at this point tho.
        } );
    }
    $big = $img ( $imageBinary );
    try {
        $ret = array ();
        foreach ( $dictionary as $key => $small ) {
            $tmp = FindImageInImageV2 ( $big, $small );
            if (empty ( $tmp )) {
                throw new \RuntimeException ( "failed to find number {$key} on the keypad!" );
            }
            if (count ( $tmp ) > 1) {
                throw new \LogicException ( "found number {$key} more than once! should never happen" );
            }
            $ret [$key] = $tmp [0];
        }
    } finally{
        imagedestroy ( $big );
    }
    return $ret;
}
// from https://stackoverflow.com/q/36002799/1067003
function FindImageInImageV2($big, $small, int $max = PHP_INT_MAX, bool $center = true): array {
    assert ( is_resource ( $small ) );
    assert ( is_resource ( $big ) );
    $ret = array ();
    // think2 ( $big, 'FindImageInImage/big' );
    // think2 ( $small, 'FindImageInImage/small' );
    $smallx = imagesx ( $small );
    $smally = imagesy ( $small );
    $bigx = imagesx ( $big );
    $bigy = imagesy ( $big );
    assert ( $bigx >= $smallx );
    if ($bigx < $smallx) {
        return $ret; // match is impossible
    }
    assert ( $bigy >= $smally );
    if ($bigy < $smally) {
        return $ret; // match is impossible
    }
    $smallcolors = imagecolorstotal ( $small );
    $bigcolors = imagecolorstotal ( $big );
    // assert($smallcolors<$bigcolors);
    if ($smallcolors > $bigcolors) {
        return $ret; // too many colors, match is impossible.
    }
    $smallImageAsColors = array ();
    for($x = 0; $x < $smallx; ++ $x) {
        $smallImageAsColors [$x] = array ();
        for($y = 0; $y < $smally; ++ $y) {
            $tmp = imagecolorsforindex ( $small, imagecolorat ( $small, $x, $y ) );
            // unset ( $tmp ['alpha'] );
            $tmp = imagecolorexact ( $big, $tmp ['red'], $tmp ['green'], $tmp ['blue'] );
            if ($tmp === - 1) {
                // small has a color that does not exist in big, match is impossible
                return $ret;
            }
            $smallImageAsColors [$x] [/*$y*/] = $tmp;
        }
    }
    unset ( $x, $y, $tmp );
    for($x = 0; $x < $bigx; ++ $x) {
        if ($bigx < ($x + $smallx)) { // << todo: can be optimized away.
            break; // too close to the end, no result possible..
        }
        for($y = 0; $y < $bigy; ++ $y) {
            if ($bigy < ($y + $smally)) { // << todo: can be optimized away.
                continue; // too close to the bottom, no result possible for this $y..
            }
            // $matchFound = true;
            for($i = 0; $i < $smallx; ++ $i) {
                for($ii = 0; $ii < $smally; ++ $ii) {
                    // yelp
                    if ($smallImageAsColors [$i] [$ii] !== imagecolorat ( $big, $x + $i, $y + $ii )) {
                        // $matchFound=false;
                        // goto outofmatching;//i can micro optimize the jumps more actually... but should i?
                        // goto uglyoptimize;
                        continue 3;
                    }
                }
            }
            // outofmatching:
            // if ($matchFound) {
            $ret [] = array (
                    'x' => ($center ? $x + (( int ) floor ( $smallx / 2 )) : $x),
                    'y' => ($center ? $y + (( int ) floor ( $smally / 2 )) : $y) 
            );
            if (count ( $ret ) >= $max) {
                // goto done;
                return $ret;
            }
            // }
            // uglyoptimize:
        }
    }
    // done:
    return $ret;
}
```

which yields the 2-dimensional X/Y locations to every number 0-9 on the keypad:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [x] => 42
            [y] => 119
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [x] => 41
            [y] => 39
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [x] => 375
            [y] => 119
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [x] => 126
            [y] => 39
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [x] => 124
            [y] => 119
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [x] => 209
            [y] => 40
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [x] => 374
            [y] => 40
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [x] => 208
            [y] => 118
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [x] => 291
            [y] => 119
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [x] => 291
            [y] => 40
        )

)
```

which you can use to emulate clicking on the keypad to enter the pin code with PHP/curl, to login. :)

the keys themselves (0-9) was extracted with [Paint.net](http://getpaint.net) like this https://youtu.be/ke4CMRjeN-o , and base64 encoded (into $dictionary), and the image search function was taken from this question: [Way to find an image inside another image in PHP/GD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36002799/1067003)

Comment: Yeah, but actually my bank website (BNP) do not send to the client the meaning of each number. The password is merge on server side thanks to the mapping used with data-id for each digit.

Comment: @fliim is the keyboard layout randomly shuffled between each login too?

Comment: @fliim that's a first! interesting indeed, here you need some OCR-like algorithm to place them... which was rather trivial to write, check the updated answer.

Comment: Interesting sample. Thanks. How do you get the base64 key of each digits ?
I'll try this out asap.

Comment: @fliim here's how i got the base64 for each digit: https://youtu.be/ke4CMRjeN-o   - the base64 command is from [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), but you can easily get the base64 from running `php -r 'echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("3.png"));'` in CMD, if you have PHP installed but not base64/cygwin installed. the image editor i used is Paint.net (which you can get from https://getpaint.net )

Comment: Ok, I did same as you. And I got successfully the positions of every digits. That's a very nice trick to avoid using an OCR. Thanks for the video you made by the way, its very kind of you. Now im not sure that curl is enough to type password and send credentials. I'll probably look for a tool that can simulate user usage with selenium or something like that. I validate your answer.