# How to detect if two images are the same with different cropping ratios?

Tags: ruby, image-processing, computer-vision, imagemagick, rmagick

I have two different images with different dimensions:

100px

[image]
[image]

and 400px

[image]
[image]

As you can see the two are clearly the "same" from a human point of view. Now I wanna detect if they are the same. I have been using image magic via the ruby gem called `rmagick` like so:

```
img1 = Magick::Image.from_blob(File.read("image_1.jpeg")).first
img2 = Magick::Image.from_blob(File.read("image_2.jpeg")).first

if img1.difference(img2).first < 4000.0 # I have found this to be a good threshold, but does not work for cropped images
  puts "they are the same!!!"
end
```

While this works well for images that have same ratio/cropping, it is not ideal when they have slightly different cropping and has been resized to the same width.

Is there a way to do it for images with different cropping? I am interested in a solution where I can say something like: One image is contained inside the other and covers somewhere around e.g. 90% of it.

PS. I can get the images in higher resolution if that helps (e.g. the double)

Comment: Not sure about RMagick, but ImageMagick's `compare` command line tool has a [`-subimage-search`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#subimage-search) switch.

Comment: That is interesting, how would a command like that look?

Comment: Never used it myself, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29062811/477037

Comment: Thanks, that is a great piece of info. I can't figure out how to do this from ruby however...

Comment: Are the images that low-quality? If no, please share bigger version of images, with more quality.

Comment: Done, see updated images...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to take a look at feature matching. The idea is to find features in two images and match them. This method is commonly used to find a template (say a logo) in another image. A feature, in essence, can be described as things that humans would find interesting in an image, such as corners or open spaces. There are many types of feature detection techniques out there however my recommendation is to use a scale-invariant feature transform (SIFT) as a feature detection algorithm. SIFT is invariant to image translation, scaling, rotation, partially invariant to illumination changes, and robust to local geometric distortion. This seems to match your specification where the images can have slightly different ratios.

Given your two provided images, here's an attempt to match the features using the [FLANN feature matcher](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html). To determine if the two images are the same, we can base it off some predetermined threshold which tracks the number of matches that pass the ratio test described in [*Distinctive Image Features from Scale-Invariant Keypoints by* *David G. Lowe*](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf). A simple explanation of the test is that the ratio test checks if matches are ambiguous and should be removed, you can treat it as a outlier removal technique. We can count the number of matches that pass this test to determine if the two images are the same. Here's the feature matching results:

[image]
[image]

[image]

```
Matches: 42
```

The dots represent all matches detected while the green lines represent the "good matches" that pass the ratio test. If you don't use the ratio test then all the points will be drawn. In this way, you can use this filter as a threshold to only keep the best matched features.

---

I implemented it in Python, I'm not very familiar with Rails. Hope this helps, good luck!

Code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load images
image1 = cv2.imread('1.jpg', 0)
image2 = cv2.imread('2.jpg', 0)

# Create the sift object
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(700)

# Find keypoints and descriptors directly
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(image2, None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image1, None)

# FLANN parameters
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)   # or pass empty dictionary
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

# Need to draw only good matches, so create a mask
matchesMask = [[0,0] for i in range(len(matches))]

count = 0
# Ratio test as per Lowe's paper (0.7)
# Modify to change threshold 
for i,(m,n) in enumerate(matches):
    if m.distance < 0.15*n.distance:
        count += 1
        matchesMask[i]=[1,0]

# Draw lines
draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0),
                   # singlePointColor = (255,0,0),
                   matchesMask = matchesMask,
                   flags = 0)

# Display the matches
result = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(image2,kp1,image1,kp2,matches,None,**draw_params)
print('Matches:', count)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Super interesting approach, I will give it a spin and get back...

Comment: @nathancy Is it so that on your example, green dots match, but blue ones not? Looks like there are too many unmatched dots?

Comment: @DracoAter good question, the blue dots represent all matches while we only draw "good matches" that pass the ratio test in green. If you don't use the ratio test then all the points will be drawn but we filter using the ratio test to draw the "better" matches. In this way, OP can use this test as a threshold to only keep the best matched features. So all the blue dots are the features that SIFT found but we filter to keep the good ones which are drawn in green

Comment: Thanks. competition was hard on the answers, many great ones :-)

Answer (score 4):

Because ImageMagick is very old, advanced and a many-featured tool, it would be difficult to build an interface that covers most of the features. As great as it is, rmagick does not (and neither do the many attempts python has taken) come close to covering all of the features.

I imagine for many use cases, it'll be safe-enough and much easier to just execute a command line method and read from that. In ruby that'll look like this;

```
require 'open3'

def check_subimage(large, small)
    stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3("magick compare -subimage-search -metric RMSE #{large} #{small} temp.jpg")
    result = stderr.gets
    stderr.close
    stdout.close
    return result.split[1][1..-2].to_f < 0.2
end

if check_subimage('a.jpg', 'b.jpg')
    puts "b is a crop of a"
else
    puts "b is not a crop of a"
end
```

I'll cover important stuff and then talk about additional notes.

The command uses magick compare to check if the second image (`small`) is a subimage of the first (`large`). This function does not check that small is strictly smaller than large (both height and width). The number I put for the similarity is 0.2 (20% error), and the value for the images you provided is about 0.15. You may want to fine tune this! I find that images that are a strict subset get less than 0.01.

- If you want less error(smaller numbers) on cases where you have 90% overlap but the second image has some extra stuff the first one doesn't, you can run it once, then crop the first large image to where the subimage is contained, then run it again with the cropped image as the "small" one and the original "small" image as the large one.
- If you really wanted a nice object oriented interface in Ruby, rmagick uses the MagicCore API. [This (link to docs)](https://imagemagick.org/api/compare.php) command is probably what you want to use to implement it, and you can open a pr to rmagick or package the cext yourself.
- Using open3 will start a thread ([see docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3)). Closing `stderr` and `stdout` is not "necessary" but you're supposed to.
- The "temp" image that's the third arg specifies a file to output an analysis onto. With a quick look, I couldn't find a way not to require it, but it does just overwrite automatically and could be good to save for debugging. For your example, it would look like this;

[image]

- The full output is in the format of 10092.6 (0.154003) @ 0,31. The first number is the rmse value out of 655535, the second one (which I use) is normalized percentage. The last two numbers represent the location of the original image from which the small image begins.
- Since there is not an objective source of truth for how "similar" images are, I picked RMSE (see more metric options [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#metric)). It's a fairly common measure of differences between values. An Absolute Error count (AE) might seem like a good idea, however it seems some cropping software does not perfectly preserve pixels so you might have to adjust fuzz and it's not a normalized value, so then you'd have to compare the error count with the size of the image and whatnot.

Comment: Thats some really great information there Carol. Thanks

Comment: Curious to know how this works for your other cases!

Comment: Thanks for the super great answer. If I could, I had given you 100p reward for this one too :-)

Answer (score 3):

Usually **template matching** have a good result in these situations. Template matching is a technique for finding areas of an image that match (are similar) to a template image (second image). This algorithm gives a score for the best macthed position in the source image (the second one).

In opencv using ***TM_CCOEFF_NORMED*** method, gives the score between 0 and 1. If the score is 1, that means the template image is exactly a part (Rect) of the source image, but if you have a little change in the lightening or perspective between the two image, the score would be lower than 1.

Now By considering a threshold for the similarity score, you can find out if they are the same or not. That threshold can be obtained by some trial and error on a few sample images. I tried your images and got the score  **0.823863**. Here is the code (opencv C++) and the common area between the two images, obtained by the matching:

[image]

```
Mat im2 = imread("E:/1/1.jpg", 1);
//Mat im2;// = imread("E:/1/1.jpg", 1);
Mat im1 = imread("E:/1/2.jpg", 1);

//im1(Rect(0, 0, im1.cols - 5, im1.rows - 5)).copyTo(im2);

int result_cols = im1.cols - im2.cols + 1;
int result_rows = im1.rows - im2.rows + 1;

Mat result = Mat::zeros(result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1);

matchTemplate(im1, im2, result, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);

double minVal; double maxVal;
Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
Point matchLoc;

minMaxLoc(result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat());

cout << minVal << " " << maxVal << " " << minLoc << " " << maxLoc << "\n";
matchLoc = maxLoc;

rectangle(im1, matchLoc, Point(matchLoc.x + im2.cols, matchLoc.y + im2.rows), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0);
rectangle(result, matchLoc, Point(matchLoc.x + im2.cols, matchLoc.y + im2.rows), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0);

imshow("1", im1);
imshow("2", result);
waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the super great answer. If I could, I had given you 100p reward for this one too :-)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [find_similar_region](https://rmagick.github.io/image2.html#find_similar_region) method. Use the smaller of the two images as the target image. Try various values for the fuzz attributes on the image and target image.

Answer (score 1):

Get the histogram of both the images and compare them. This would work very well for crop and Zoom unless there is too drastic a change because of these.

This is better than the current approach where you are directly subtracting the images. But this approach still has few.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will take a look at it.

Comment: This isn't a very useful answer as it doesn't demonstrate how to accomplish the goal. It's the equivalent of "Google this term and figure it out yourself."

Comment: Histogram is one of the first things people learn in image processing. If some has to google it, then I deeply apologize.